# My MANIFEST.in content installed to distinct location from rest of package

Tags: python, manifest, setuptools

I am creating a package in python with setuptools. I am using a MANIFEST.in file to include a dependency that my package utilizes. I specify the contents of the MANIFEST.in as below:

> recursive-include package/dependency_directory *

The package builds and installs without error. However, when I call the package from one of the entry points I see that the script fails because it cannot find the correct filepath to the contents of MANIFEST.in.

The path that the package is looking at is this:

> /Users/Xerez/Library/Caches/Python-Eggs/qasar-0.1-py2.7.egg-tmp/qasar/fastqc/fastqc

The rest of the package is installed at:

> /Users/Xerez/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qasar-0.1-py2.7.egg

However, inside my IDE when I ask where the package is using the code below:

```
DATA_PATH = pkg_resources.resource_filename('qasar', 'fastqc/fastqc')
```

I get the following filepath:

> /Users/Xerez/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qasar-0.1-py2.7.egg/qasar/fastqc/fastqc

When I run the script from within the IDE using this path everything works fine. I recognize that MANIFEST.in is installing in a distinct location from the rest of the package and that my IDE is calling yet another distinct form of python. How may I force the installation to put everything in the same version_of_anaconda/location?

I attach [a link](https://bitbucket.org/arp2012/stackoverflow/src/master/) to a bitbucket repository which has a stripped down version of the package that may assist in answering this question.The link is also written below:

> https://bitbucket.org/arp2012/stackoverflow/src/master/

I apologize if the answer to this question is trivial, but I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem for a bit and decided to ask for help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @hoefling thank you for your response. I have attached code to help your review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I was able to solve the multiple python path issue by installing the package inside of a docker container that only had one version of python and anaconda installed. This solution, however, is neither ideal nor elegant.